# I want to get element in variable without ClientId in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to get element in 'textbox' variable without ClientId

```
        function fncInputDateTimeOnly() {
    var textBox = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtFilingStartDate");
                    var textLength = textBox.value.length;
                    if (textLength >= 10) {
                        event.returnValue = false;
                    }

    <asp:TextBox ID="txttDate" onkeypress="fncInputDateTimeOnly()" runat="server" Width="195px" />
```

Above code is working perfectly but I want to do this and its not working

```
 function fncInputDateTimeOnly() {
        var textBox = this; //how to get the element in variable
                        var textLength = textBox.value.length;
                        if (textLength >= 10) {
                            event.returnValue = false;
                        }
```

Comment: Not really clear. What is not working? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` as a parameter to the method.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttDate" onkeypress="fncInputDateTimeOnly(this)" runat="server" Width="195px" />
```

```
function fncInputDateTimeOnly(textBox) {
    var textLength = textBox.value.length;
    ...
```